# Scalalab imported routines not found

Tags: scala, scalalab

I have not enough reputation to create tag "ScalaLab" :(
I'm studying ScalaLabAllDraftUserGuideJune142013.pdf 
When I enter first example:

```
var a = ones0(20, 30) // creates a zero-indexed 20X30 matrix filled with ones
var b = ones0(30, 50)
var c = a * b
```

console displays:

```
<console>:7: error: not found: value ones0
       var a = ones0(20, 30) // creates a zero-indexed 20X30 matrix filled with ones
               ^
<console>:8: error: not found: value ones0
       var b = ones0(30, 50)
               ^
Error
```

Imports do not help.
Could anyone help?

Comment: I think you missed the function definition for ones0.

Comment: Where is ones0 supposed to be defined? In Scalalab?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you! I solved this at

https://code.google.com/p/scalalab/issues/detail?id=15

> From the "Scala Interpreter" menu,
>   you can choose the preferred library (EJML works faster),
>   and then all the ScalaLab imported routines (as e.g. ones0)
>   will work well.
>
> ... it's better to avoid JEIGEN library, because the native routines,
>   currently do not work on Windows, but they work on Linux